# javafx font issue with quran text

Tags: javafx, arabic

I'm developing desktop Quran app in javaFX, but I'm facing some issues with Quran ayahs symbols.
I'm using **Scheherazade-Regular.ttf** fonts and in java using like this:

```
Font arabicFont = Font.loadFont(getClass().getResource("/fonts/Scheherazade-Regular.ttf").toExternalForm(), 35);
Label ayah = new Label(ayah.getContent());
ayah.setPrefWidth(rootPane.getPrefWidth());
ayah.setWrapText(true);
ayah.setAlignment(Pos.BASELINE_RIGHT);
ayah.setTextAlignment(TextAlignment.RIGHT);
ayah.setFont(arabicFont);
```

this is how is showing in app

[image]

but I want to show something like this:

[image: desired result]

Comment: Post a [mcve]..

Comment: looks the same to me except the yellow letter (?) - is it?

Comment: thanks for inlining the images, now they look different indeed ;) can it be a problem with the font itself? does it show up correctly in a non-fx context?

Comment: What is this line `Label ayah = new Label(ayah.getContent());`? `ayah` is not defined yet when you call `getContent()` on it. Follow the link in the first comment.

Comment: @kleopatra yes they look different in second image which I got from this api http://corpus.quran.com/java/download.jsp. From this api I can export in png, html or text. Only as images are rendering properly. Also this site https://read.quranexplorer.com/18/1/110/Usmani/Mishari-Rashid/Hide/Tajweed-ON use same fonts on web and the look good.
@user1803551 By `Label ayah = new Label(ayah.getContent());`  I'm generating ayahs in runtime and adding into listview, `getContent` is ayah content which I'm getting from sqlite db.

Comment: Again, if you want further help follow the link in the first comment. SQL has nothing to do with font rendering. Create a stage with a scene with a label with this text hardcoded. Post this code.